# Running Java class (not an servlet) on GlassFish 4 server

Tags: jakarta-ee, web-applications, glassfish, glassfish-4, java-ee-7

I have the following two questions:

1. How to start a java class (not a servlet or JavaBean) on `GlassFish 4` server via Eclipse Juno or otherwise?
2. What is the proper way to run it on **start-up**?

I have Java class that uses `JDNI` functionality and needs to run on the server.  How it can be done?

I found some information about running it on server start-up, which boiled down to the following options:

- using both `@Startup` and `@Singleton` annotations (which, as I understand, are specifically for EJBs)
- implementing `LifecycleListener` interface
- implementing  `Startup` interface

Oracle GlassFish Server  Application Development Guide clearly states:

> Lifecycle listener modules are deprecated. Support for them is
>   included for backward compatibility. Implementing the
>   org.glassfish.api.Startup interface instead is recommended.

When I added `org.glassfish.api.*` import and had my class to implement `Startup` interface `Eclipse` warned me that it was deprecated.  So I'm not sure what's left there since my class is **not EJB**.  I went ahead with `Startup interface` anyway and to satisfy its it  requirements added the following method:

```
@Override
public Lifecycle getLifecycle() {
    return Lifecycle.SERVER;
}
```

In Eclipse I stopped and started the server but the class seemingly did not run.  My class has System.out.println() call but I did not see its message either in Server and Console tabs nor in the server log.

So this is were I stuck.

Would appreciate your suggestions.

**CLARIFICATION:**

My start-up related part of the questions refers to **server** (i.e. `GlassFish`) start-up (and not a web application start-up).  I need to force `GlassFish` to instantiate this class when the server starts and let it run for the duration of the server life.

It is basically a Message Listener that need to be up to monitor a queue and respond to request from various senders.

Comment: Is it a problem your class becoming an EJB? There is usually nothing that will do it harm.

Comment: @rdcrng - This task is from the book I'm using and comes before the chapter on EJBs.  So I accepted it as a challenge but got stuck.

Comment: Well, on a server, anything should be invoked by something else - such as servlets, web services, EJBs, timers (which are tied to EJBs), JMS, etc. I don't think you can get around using some of that.

Comment: @rdcrng - I'm under impression that there should be a way to tell GlassFish to load a certain *plain* class on server start-up. Such *instruction* could be in annotation,  interface, XML or any combination of the three.

Comment: If it does exist, I'm not aware of it _shrug_

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html

Comment: @JBNizet -  I must be thick today. How does your link apply to my question?

Comment: You want something to happen at startup of your application, and this is how you can define a listener which is called when the application starts up (i.e. is deployed). The javadoc of contextInitialized() is: "Receives notification that the web application initialization process is starting.". So you define a listener, implement this method, and do whatever you want at startup.

Comment: @JBNizet I want something to happen when a **server** starts up (not an application).

Comment: If you deploy an application on Glassfish, it will start when the server starts, and stop when the server stops. That's the whole point of an application server: run server-side applications.

Comment: @JBNizet - May be we differ in terminology.  I currently have 5 web applications deployed on the server. None of them runs until I explicitly initiate them. I mean that they do not start performing their tasks **automatically** after `asadmin start-domain` (or its Eclipse equivalent) is completed.

Comment: What do you mean by "initiate"? Are you saying that you must redeploy the application each time you restart the server? I have 0 experience with Glassfish, but I would be very surprised if you had to do that. What task are you talking about in "they do not start performing their tasks"?

Comment: GlassFish do startup deployed applications on startup. Well kinda. Application Clients does not. For them to be able to launch, one has to redeploy the entire GlasFish application.

Comment: PM.. what book are you reading? I'm curious. I want challenges too!

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you can't make your message listener class a message-driven EJB? That's what message-driven beans are designed to do.

Comment: @ Martin Andersson - I read a book that was written using `Java 6` and `GlassFish 3.x`, but I decided to install `Java `7 and `GlassFish 4`.  So I have to do minimal adaptation.  Here it is: [http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Java-Programming-24-Hour-Trainer.productCd-0470889640.html]. Look at reviews on Amazon and believe those that say that there a lot of typos and some errors, while errata is not complete (to say the least).

Comment: @IanEvans  - As I have explained way above, `EJB`s (including `MDB`s) are introduced in the next chapter.  So, I assumed there should be away to accomplish the same without that.  On the other hand, the point that my class is not an `servlet` is actually a mute one, since I can always create a bare-bone one that instantiates the class.

Comment: @PM77-1 - Is your listener using JNI ("Java Native Interface", i.e. native applications written in some other language), or JNDI ("Java Naming and Directory Interface", i.e. a way of referring to and looking up resources and components in a standard way)? I also think you'll find it much easier to accomplish your goals if you start out using the correct technology, and not depending on the learning path of a book. The point of, e.g., Java EE is to simplify network application development. Trying to recreate the same features in Java SE first is extremely difficult.